# Awk if else issues

Tags: if-statement, awk, syntax

Bash points an arrow to "else" and says "syntax error" in a provocative whining tone.

```
awk '{if($3 != 0) a = ($3/$4) print $0, a; else if($3==0) print $0, "-" }' file > out
```

Why?

Answer (score 41):

You forgot braces around the if block, and a semicolon between the statements in the block.

```
awk '{if($3 != 0) {a = ($3/$4); print $0, a;} else if($3==0) print $0, "-" }' file > out
```

Comment: Still getting division by zero attempted

Comment: @AWE: Add a test to deal with `$4` being 0.

Comment: I did, then I awk for it and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Aha! I had carriage return issues. This helped me with it: sed 's/.$//'

Comment: Well sed helped me but I had turned it around $4/$3, $3/$4 still gives me zero division.

Comment: As @Dennis Williamson already said... If your data contains zero values for the fourth field, you will need a test like `if ($4==0) {<do something useful>} else...`

Answer (score 5):

Try the code

```
awk '{s=($3==0)?"-":$3/$4; print s}'
```